# Append from one select list to another (Apex 4.2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, oracle-apex

I have two select list page items in APEX 4.2 (`X` and `Y`)

`X` is populated by a cascading drop down list to provide its values. I want to be able to pull only certain values from `X` into `Y` via a dynamic action and then be able to change the cascading list (`X`) to another selection and continue to append to list `Y`.

Currently, I have the following JavaScript expression using a `set value` action for appending to `Y`:

```
var target_val = $('#P1_X').find(":selected").val();
var target_text = $('#P1_X').find(":selected").text();

$('#P1_Y).append($('<option/>', {
    value: target_val,
    text: target_text
}));
```

But this is not being picked up at all by list `Y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this-

In order to append from one list to the other you can create the following function which appends and disables the selected option using an 'onclick' function call:

```
function getValues(X){
  var list = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      if (obj.options[i].selected && !obj.options[i].disabled) {
        obj.options[i].disabled=true;
         list += '<optionvalue="'+obj.options[i].value+'">'+obj.options[i].innerHTML+'</option>';
      }
   }
  document.getElementById('Y').innerHTML += list;
}
```

I then was able to give users the option to remove their selected option if they needed to make any changes, re-appending options to the bottom of the list:

```
function removeValues(Y){
  var arr = []; //array so we can repopulate target list
  var el = document.getElementById('X');
     for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if (obj.options[i].selected) {
         arr.push('<option value="'+obj.options[i].value+'">'+obj.options[i].innerHTML+'</option>');

         $("select:not(#"+$(obj).parent().attr('id')+") option[value="+$(obj).val()+"]").detach();
             }
           }
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
              el.innerHTML += arr[i];
           }
     }
```